# I tried to run OpenGl but the GLUT screen is just rendering a white screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, glut

I have just tried to run the Bresenham function which draws a line from 2 vertexes, but only the white screen of GLUT appear, there is no line at all. Here is my source code, can anybody help me?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);
}
void Bresenham(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    int Dx = abs(x2 - x1);
    int Dy = abs(y2 - y1);
    int p = 2 * Dy - Dx;
    int c1 = 2 * Dy;
    int c2 = 2 * (Dy - Dx);
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;
    int x_unit = 1, y_unit = 1;
    glVertex2d(x, y);
    while (x != x2) {
        if (p<0) p += c1;
        else {
            p += c2;
            y += y_unit;
        }
        x += x_unit;
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    }
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    Bresenham(50, 150, 300, 200);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
    glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("Line");
    init();
    int x1=50, y1=150, x2=300, y2=200;
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don’t check for any errors anywhere. That would be a good start

Comment: If you draw a white line on a white background, does it make a sound?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your background color doesn't match your drawing color.  Kinda hard to see white-on-white :)

Drawing the line in red works on my machine:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Bresenham(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int Dx = abs(x2 - x1);
    int Dy = abs(y2 - y1);
    int p = 2 * Dy - Dx;
    int c1 = 2 * Dy;
    int c2 = 2 * (Dy - Dx);
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;
    int x_unit = 1, y_unit = 1;
    glVertex2d(x, y);
    while (x != x2)
    {
        if (p<0)
            p += c1;
        else
        {
            p += c2;
            y += y_unit;
        }
        x += x_unit;
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    Bresenham(50, 150, 300, 200);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Line");
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```